# Sending POST data to external webservice

Tags: visualforce

How do I send post data from a visualforce page to an external webservice (say foobar.com/someLink) with some data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 public static void sendRequest(){
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http(); 

        req.setMethod('POST' ); // Method Type
        req.setEndpoint('foobar.com/someLink'); // Server Url
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); // Content Type
        req.setBody('userName=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(userName, 'UTF-8') +   
        "&password=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(password, 'UTF-8') + '&cardNumber=' +  
        cardNumber); // Request Parameters
        try {
            res = http.send(req);
            if(res.getBody() != null){
                // Parse Response
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('error: '+ e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Passing user name and password for authentication not good approach.Using oauth is recommended .Thanks

Comment: I just gave an example @Mohit. well thanks for suggestion

Comment: Welcome.This was necessary as people googling sometimes see that and follow wrong practice .

Answer (score 3):

```
//This is a common Utility Class for POST request to the  External System

public static string initiateRequest(String Body,String requestUrl){

    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint(requestUrl);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');//Set the Proper Header
    req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
    req.setBody(Body);//JSON body as String 
    Oauth1 reuest=new Oauth1();//If oauth is required implement an Oauth Class to set the Authorisation Header
    reuest.sign(req);//Call the method to sign in as per Oauth rules
    HttpResponse res=new HttpResponse();
    try{
     res=h.send(req);

     if(res.getStatusCode()!=201){

        //log the error
     }

    }catch (Exception e){
       //log the error
    }
    System.debug('RESPONSE BODY'+ res.getBody());
    return res.getBody();//Response Bosy Generated

}
```

Please find the above Class that i used as Utility for POST request.

The String body you will have to construct necessary JSON

The request URL is the URL of the external service

The header Authorization parameter you may set depending on whether external system uses oauth 1.0 or oauth 2.0.

From the visualforce Page you may call this above  on the action of button.

Use JSON.serialise to generate JSON data from apex Object .

Comment: Why are you checking for res.getStatusCode()!=201?

Shouldn't you check for a 200 response?

Comment: @RyanGuest the server response can be 201 and 200 too.Depends on how its implemented on server.So may be i can check for OR of both to be on safe side .

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava. I closely follow your answers in salesforce stackexchange. I wanted to know how do I authenticate a user of an external application on the click of a button in opportunity details page and then send encrypted opp details to external web app?

Comment: any reference you would want me to follow?. Thanks in advance

Comment: @MNZ .It will depend on authentication mechanism of your external server .Some Servers follow BASIC ,some NTLM.Some oauth .So find out whats the authentication mechanism you need and then we can apporach solitioning

Comment: @Giene It's a method and needs to be wrapped in a class .As a developer please uunderstand method and classes and how methods are included in classes. Also there is a polite way to begin conversation.Feel free to ping me and discuss any issue you see with way answer questions here or anywhere.

Comment: @Giene The answers that's  provided on stackexchange are for reference and help you get closer. They are not perfect solution and complete code and should not be merely copy pasted as you are trying to do here .And again there is a polite way of pointing things. Also this website gives you power to downvote .You should be using that providing specific reasons and instead initiating conversation in this format might be less helpful .